# Get username in Asp.Net Core Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What is the accepted way to get the username of a Asp.Net Core REST service inside of the controller? Assuming the authentication is done by JWT?

I see `User.Claims.First().Value` contains the username, but is it always going to be in the first claim?

Or is there some better way to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `FindFirst()` function on the `ClaimsPrincipal` class.

Examples:

```
// using built in claim types
User.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); 

// using custom claim type
User.FindFirst("username");
```